# Fallo en formulario HTML - Conexión BBDD PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, configuración

Tengo un sencillo formulario para conectarme a una página web mediante usuario/password, funciona correctamente pero el error es el siguiente: se recarga automáticamente los valores del usuario/password del archivo config.inic.php cuando creo que no tiene nada que ver.

¿Por qué cuando ejecuto/cargo la página me carga los valores?

Código COMPLETO del fichero **index.php:**

```
<?php
     //Crea una sesión para ser usada mediante una petición GET o POST.
    session_start(); 
    include_once "conexion.php";

    //Función para comprobar el login del usuario.
    function verificar_login($con, $usuario, $password, &$result) {
        $count = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' and password='".$password."'";
        if($rec = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($rec);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rec)) {
                $result = $row;
            }
            //Liberar el conjunto de resultados.
            mysqli_free_result($rec);
        }
        //Cerrar la conexión.
        mysqli_close($con);
        return $count;
    }

    //Si existe la sesión...
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_id'])) {
        //Si fue pulsado el botón "Login"...
        if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            //Sanear variables.
            $usuario = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "usuario", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
            $password = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

            if(verificar_login($con, $usuario, $password, $result) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $result->idusuario;
                $_SESSION['usuario_nombre'] = $result->usuario;
                header("location:index.php");
            }else{
                echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto. Inténtelo nuevamente.</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css"> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario: </label><input name="usuario" type="text"></div>
            <div><label>Password: </label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="Entrar"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }else{
        if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_nombre'])) {
            echo 'El usuario '.$_SESSION['usuario_nombre'].' ingresó correctamente.';
        }
        echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
?>
```

**Código del HTML:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="login">
            <div><label>Usuario: </label><input name="usuario" type="text"></div>
            <div><label>Password: </label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="Entrar"></div>
        </form>
```

**Código del config.inic.php:**

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';      // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

**Adjuntada captura de pantalla.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que tengas activado en el navegador el auto-llenado de formularios, o puede que tengas en tu página código Javascript/jQuery que cargue los valores. En ese segundo caso, revisa el código fuente de esa página.

Comment: Buscare la primera opción debido a que en mi codigo aún no existe js ni jquery.

Comment: Aun eliminando el autocompletado de formularios me sigue saliendo esos valores al cargar la página.

Comment: Es muy extraño. Por si te sirve, yo protejo de este modo mis archivos de configuración : https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO/blob/master/db.php.ini Haciéndolo así no hay posibilidad alguna de que salga en pantalla lo que contiene el archivo, sobre todo si se trata de información sensible.

Comment: Y como sabes que no te llegan los datos ? podias poner el codigo que has probado en index.php para saber si estas recogiendo bien los datos post ? a ver si eso ayuda

Comment: Añado mi fichero index.php

Comment: El tema es que en algún sitio web que hayas accedido desde ese navegador y le hayas dado guardar credenciales, entonces el te pone esas mismas en donde el formulario tenga un campo usuario y otro clave. Para solucionar esto elimina tu historial completo y pon en tu formulario **<form autocomplete="off"**

Comment: He borrado TODO el historia de Google Chrome, he borrado el autocompletado de formularios en Configuración, he borrado el historial, he añadido "form autocomplete="off" y me sigue saliendo el llenado de datos de Login/Password automáticamente.

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que el problema ocurre en Chrome, en Firefox me salen los campos vacíos.

Answer (score 0):

hola parece que se autorellena, prueba de esta manera

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="login.php" name="loginform" autocomplete="off" role="form" class="form-signin">
```

Saludos